# Serialization proxy

Tags: java, serialization

I've read that we should serialize only logical part of objects.

> Using the default serialized form when an object’s physical
>   representation differs substantially from its logical data content has
>   four disadvantages:
>
> ...//they relate to default serialization form and have no relation to
>   subject
>
> //and about linked list of Strings:
>
> A reasonable serialized form
>   for StringList is simply the number of strings in the list, followed
>   by the strings themselves. This constitutes the logical data
>   represented by a StringList, stripped of the details of its physical
>   representation.
>
> *Effective Java (2nd Edition), Item 75*

And in case of linked list it means that we should not serialize any implementation details like nodes relation, but in fact only "list of elements".

I have linked list implementation, and want to implement *Serialization Proxy pattern*(*Effective Java (2nd Edition), Item 78*) in it, but also not to violate rule above. There is another quote:

> The serialization proxy pattern is reasonably straightforward. First, design a private static nested class of the serializable class
>   that **concisely represents the logical state of an instance** of the
>   enclosing class. This nested class, known as the serialization proxy,
>   should have a single constructor, whose parameter type is the
>   enclosing class. This constructor merely copies the data from its
>   argument: it need not do any consistency checking or defensive
>   copying. By design, the **default serialized form of the serialization
>   proxy is the perfect serialized form** of the enclosing class.

So is it only right to serialize logical state of object in Serialization Proxy class(as i've done below) or for example serialization of list's head node which is implementation details is right too?

Note : `List` interface and `LinkedList` class are my own implementations, not `java.util`.

```
//...
private static class SerializationProxy<E> implements Serializable {
        private final E[] elements;

        SerializationProxy(List<? extends E> list) {
            elements = list.toArray(Object.class); //returns array with all elements
        }

        private Object readResolve() {
            return new LinkedList<E>(elements); //constructor that take array and wraps it back in LinkedList
        }

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 123131234141423234L;
    }


    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws InvalidObjectException {
    throw new InvalidObjectException("Proxy required");
    }

    private Object writeReplace() {
        return new SerializationProxy<E>(this); //pass enclosing class for proxy serializtion
    }
//...
```

If something isn't clear here's [full implementation.](https://github.com/Jskyi/LinkedList/blob/master/src/com/gmail/gwini777/Lists/main/LinkedList.java)  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just serialize the list. You don't need to do this. But what you're doing doesnt make sense. It will recourse indefinitely. The proxy doesn't need a `writeReplace()` method, it needs a `readResolve()` method.

Comment: @EJP my proxy has `readResolve()`, `readResolve()` belong to enclosing class. And i forget to note that `List` is my own interface, not  `java.util`, sorry.

Comment: Doesnt make any difference really. Just make your `List` class `Serializable`. There's no need for any of this, unless maybe you're planning on having lists with tens of thousands of elements.  You seem to be doing it right post your edit, at least what you've posted here. Nobody is going to chase links.

Comment: @EJP I do this in educational purpose, want to learn proper use of this pattern. And we shouldn't simply make class `implements Serializable` if it logical data differs from its physical representation(case of linked list) and if we want to ensure security.

Comment: OK well try it and see what happens. Print some traces so you can see what's happening.

Comment: @EJP It works well, but i want to know whether i done this properly because in Effective Java book example physical representations of object is as same as it logical state.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the question. Can you post the *entire* quotation, including enough context so we know what you're talking about? Edit it into your question.

Comment: Hope now it's clear.

Comment: It isn't. I asked quite specifically for something that you simply have not provided.

Comment: I've added comments.

Comment: I asked you for an exact and full quotation of what you are reading, which NB should include a proper citation, and enough context so we can understand your question. Still waiting.

Comment: Sigh. How exactly is that 'exact and full' when you don't list the 'four disadvantages'? I will add that I'm unaware of the security issue you mentioned in passing, and that the logical/physical distinction you mention seems arbitrary in the case of a linked list. There are *technical* reasons (recursion) to serialize it as you have done, or via custom `readObject()/writeObject()` methods, but some of this is starting to sound like received dogma, which I am highly allergic to, having been around long enough to see off most of them.

Comment: But these disadvantages have no relation with serialization proxy, they about default serialization form. And why only technical reasons? We can simply serialize pointer to head node of list instead of array(if do `Serializable`) it , but it's implementation details and violate rule that i've mentioned.

Comment: I cannot and will not discuss this further with you until you post the exact and entire text that you're talking about. Not a paraphrase, which is all I have now. Until then, this is not a real question.

Comment: Now I did everything I could

Comment: Good, thank you, so what part of your question haven't I already answered? Please bear in mind that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Thsi part: _is it only right to serialize logical state of object in Serialization Proxy class(as i've done below) or for example serialization of list's head node which is implementation details is right too?_ Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it only right to serialize logical state of object in Serialization Proxy class(as i've done below)

That's what your quotations say.

> or for example serialization of list's head node which is implementation details is right too?

That's exactly what your quotations warn against.

Not that I necessarily agree with the citation. I have no in-principle objection to serializing links, for example. There may be *practical* objections, such as recursion depth, but that's a different matter.

It's difficult to understand why you had to post this question, when you already had a respected citation, and when you had already implemented the answer, which in turn indicates that you had understood what you had read.